# Which Terry Pratchett book starts with "Zoom in"?

Tags: story-identification, quotes, terry-pratchett

This is driving me crazy. I think it's one of the Bromeliad Trilogy, where the narration starts like.

> Start with the earth. Find somewhere green. Zoom in, zoom in further. A tree. Zoom in even more. A flower in the side of the tree. Now zoom in even further, and there is a frog.

The flower is a bromeliad plant, which is why I think it's part of that trilogy, also known as Nomes.

But I haven't got access to the books, and I can't find the quote online.

Which book was this in?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Chapter 12 of [*Wings*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?976) starts out:

> Find a blue planet...
>
> *Focus*
>
> This is a planet. Most of it is covered with water, but it's still called Earth.
>
> Find a country...
>
> *Focus*
>
> ...blues and greens and browns under the sun, and
> long wisps of rain cloud being torn by the mountains...
>
> *Focus*
>
> ...on a mountain, green and dripping, and there's a...
>
> *Focus*
>
> ...tree, hung with moss and covered with flowers, and...
>
> *Focus*
>
> ...on a flower with a little pool in it, is an epiphytic bromeliad.

It's possible you're confusing this zoom in on the bromeliad with the start of the story which zooms in on a nome in a dustbin at an airport:

> Let the eye of your imagination be a camera...
>
> This is the universe, a glittering ball of galaxies like the ornament on some
> unimaginable Christmas tree.
>
> Find a galaxy...
>
> *Focus*
>
> This is a galaxy, swirled like the cream in a cup of coffee, every pinpoint of
> light a star.
>
> Find a star...
>
> *Focus*
>
> This is a solar system, where planets barrel through the darkness around the
> central fires of the sun. Some planets hug close, hot enough to melt lead.
> Some drift far out, where the comets are born.
>
> Find a blue planet...
>
> *Focus*
>
> This is a planet. Most of it is covered in water. It's called Earth.
>
> Find a country...
>
> *Focus*
>
> ...blues and greens and browns under the sun, and
> here's a pale oblong, which is...
>
> *Focus*
>
> ...an airport, a concrete hive for silver bees. There's a...
>
> *Focus*
>
> ...building full of people and noise, and...
>
> *Focus*
>
> ...a hall of lights and bustle, and...
>
> *Focus*
>
> ...a bin full of rubbish, and...
>
> *Focus*
>
> ...a pair of tiny eyes...
>
> *Focus*
>
> ...
>
> *Focus*
>
> ...
>
> *Focus*
>
> ...
>
> *Click!*
>
> Masklin slid cautiously down an old burger carton

Comment: I should have *nome* ! It's *focus* not *zoom*. Thanks for finding this!

Comment: I feel like this is a common trope in many Pratchett books--I feel like at least a couple of the Discworld books start with an imaginary pan in to the Disc.